# Was there a secret meeting of Nazis in 1944 to plan for the EU?

Tags: nazi-germany

(This is based on [this closed question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45603/was-the-eu-created-or-supported-by-nazis). Rather than ask about the whole thesis I'm picking one specific claim which should be answerable.)

The book "*[Indisputable Evidence Proving The EU Was Created By Nazis](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Indisputable-Evidence-Proving-Created-Nazis-ebook/dp/B07MMHNL96)*" by Jack King tries to show that the EU was actually planned and created by Nazis as a way to ensure German domination of Europe. One claim in particular caught my eye:

> 1944: A secret conference was held in Berlin entitled "How Germany will dominate the peace when it loses the war". Rich and powerful Germans moved huge amounts of money out of Germany and sent it to America until after the Nuremberg Trials had been completed. The money was needed to pay to fight for a German dominated Europe. Nazis agreed that their backup plan for European domination would take years to reach fruition if the war was lost but believed that their economic and political tactics would prove successful.

Is there any evidence that such a meeting took place? If so, when, where and who? What plan emerged from this meeting?

Comment: During the war, all sides had meetings with plans for how to carve up and govern Europe in various possible outcomes. European unity (with Soviets, without Soviets) was certainly discussed by the Allies as well, and strongly promoted by the UK after the war – hence Churchill being listed among the EU's "Founding Fathers". Read about some of the wartime conferences and post-war discussions to get context.

Comment: Does this tome of "Indisputable evidence" offer *any* actual factual evidence to back up this extraordinary set of claims, does it just spin a narrative for its target audience to take for granted? Because this sounds like a grandiose pile of hogwash combining multiple mutually contradictory conspiracy theories.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Well, yeah. Some of those concepts had actually already been discussed *before* WW2, because after "The Great War" people felt that maybe warfare had become a little too costly for everyone involved, and a stronger forum for people to work out their differences *before* things escalated into warfare was a good idea...

Comment: @Shadur Indeed — cf. League of Nations, designed to promote world peace and disintegrated when it failed to prevent WW2.

Comment: @Shadur No it doesn't. The "bibliography" at the end seems to be mostly (if not entirely) tracts of the same kind, along with a caution against relying on sources such as the BBC which have taken EU money. I agree with your evaluation of the book overall, but its still a notable claim and worth looking in to. Note that the claim is not merely that at some point some people thought about post-war Europe, its that senior people in the Nazi government conceived of the EU as Plan B after Plan A (WW2) had failed.

Comment: The question title talks about the EU, as in: the European Union. But the quote and question talk about a continent where everything will be controlled by Germany. These are not the same. Can you clarify how a continent controlled by Germany relates to the democratic political union between European nations?

Comment: The thesis of the book is that the EU is actually the Nazi party in disguise. See the linked original question for more details. As I said, rather than trying to ask about all the claims in the book I'm just picking one out as it seems fairly central.

Comment: @PaulJohnson If the book itself offers no evidence, then it's pretty certain that there is none, and asking this question is simply promoting a conspiracy theory.

Comment: @DenisS I think you are correct. As is typical for conspiracy theories of this kind, a dubious piece of evidence is cherry-picked for support while ignoring all the other evidence which contradicts it. I'll flag this as a dupe, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was the EU created or supported by Nazis?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45603/was-the-eu-created-or-supported-by-nazis)